# Understanding SSE3 Matrix Multiplication Optimization

Tags: c++, sse

With reference to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xiangfan/archive/2009/04/28/optimize-your-code-matrix-multiplication.aspx.

```
template<>
void SeqMatrixMult4(int size, float** m1, float** m2, float** result)
{
    Transpose(size, m2);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            __m128 c = _mm_setzero_ps();

            for (int k = 0; k < size; k += 4) {
                c = _mm_add_ps(c, _mm_mul_ps(_mm_load_ps(&m1[i][k]), _mm_load_ps(&m2[j][k])));
            }
            c = _mm_hadd_ps(c, c);
            c = _mm_hadd_ps(c, c);
            _mm_store_ss(&result[i][j], c);
        }
    }
    Transpose(size, m2);
}
```

Why is there 2 more `_mm_hadd_ps(c, c)` after the inner most for loop? To verify my understanding: this code loads 4 floats from m1 and another 4 from m2, then multiplies them resulting in 4 floats (`__m128`). Then I sum them into `c` (at this point, its still 4 floats?). Then after the for loop I `hadd` this result twice? What does that do?

---

My code slightly re-written produces the wrong result it appears

```
long long start, end;
__m128 v1, v2, vMul, vRes;
vRes = _mm_setzero_ps();

start = wall_clock_time();
transpose_matrix(m2);
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        float tmp = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k+=4) {
            v1 = _mm_load_ps(&m1[i][k]);
            v2 = _mm_load_ps(&m2[j][k]);
            vMul = _mm_mul_ps(v1, v2);

            vRes = _mm_add_ps(vRes, vMul);
        }
        vRes = _mm_hadd_ps(vRes, vRes);
        _mm_store_ss(&result[i][j], vRes);
    }
}
end = wall_clock_time();
fprintf(stderr, "Optimized Matrix multiplication took %1.2f seconds\n", ((float)(end - start))/1000000000);

// reverse the transposition
transpose_matrix(m2);
```

Comment: That seems to work on 4x4 matrix? I need it for 1024x1024 to 4K x 4k matrixes

Comment: The just use MKL/Goto BLAS/ATLAS. For large matrix multiplication you need to do multi-level cache blocking, but if you never did it before, it would take few weeks to implement and tune. SIMD will give you only a small fraction of performance boost of cache blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`haddps` doesn't sum all four elements in a vector.  Two `haddps` instructions are needed to get the full horizontal sum.

If we number the elements of the vector `{c0,c1,c2,c3}`, the first `haddps` produces `{c0+c1, c2+c3, c0+c1, c2+c3}`.  The second produces `{c0+c1+c2+c3, <same thing in the other lanes>}`.

Comment: Fair enough, but then `_mm_store_ss` will just store the 1st element of the vector? Isnt clear when I read the docs on MSDN.